# How can i get how to scrolled it is in uicollectionView

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I’m using uicollectionview in storyboard.

When uicollectionview scroll down i want get how scrolled down In pixels

For example, if i swipe one finger, return 200 pixels.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the scroll event with `UIScrollViewDelegate` and

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) { }
```

Now, you can have the scroll position with `scrollView.contentOffset` it's a `CGPoint`, so with a conversion (point to pixel) you should get the numbers of Pixel.

```
scrollView.contentOffset.y * UIScreen.main.scale
```

This should works.